# $location.search() effects other tabs in the browser

Tags: angularjs

I have an application which will often require several tabs open.  When I change the URL on one tab using `$location.search()` the URL in the other tabs are also changed.

I'm not having any luck replicating this on plunkr or jsfiddle.

Comment: Are you perhaps using BrowserSync?

Comment: I am, but this is happening even when I run it from the dist folder (so no BrowserSync).

Comment: How exactly are you running the application? What's the difference between dev and dist? Are you using gulp/grunt?

Comment: Gulp seemed to be the issue.  The problem disappeared when I ran gulp build and uploaded the dist folder to the live server.